# How to prevent multiple code execution on checkbox click in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

On my page I have a checkboxes like this:

```
<input id="check0" type="checkbox">
```

Each time user check or uncheck it I want to execute some jQuery code. Here's sample of this code:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // Calculate something here
    }
    else {
        // Or calculate something here         
    }
});
```

Here's the problem: if user will click on checkbox multiple time really quick, some of the code will be executed multiple times, because it will trigger click function every time, but browser will not change 'check' status that quick!

How to prevent this?

I thought to put something like:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // Disable checkbox
        $(this).disabled = true;

        // Calculate something here

        // Enable it back
        $(this).disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        // Or calculate something here         
    }
});
```

How can I make my code to execute exact in this sequence? Disable > then execute code > then enable back?

Thanks

Comment: Checkout jQuery $.when and then. Maybe those will help you out.

Comment: You should be able to check the disabled flag and only execute code if it is not disabled

Comment: Your `disabled` changes are not doing what you think they're doing. While this function (your click handler) is executing, the UI will be locked- meaning that the browser won't accept a *click* while your function is executing. So unless your 'calculate something' bit is actually asynchronous, you can remove the disabled part.

Answer (score -1):

You should use on change, not on click. Then check the prop checked. If checked, run code. If you want to disable, use attr.

Try this...

```
$("#check0").on("change", function () {
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
        alert("hey now");
        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
    } else {
        //nothing
    }   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Eddieflux/z3xfcmgk/